# Hibernate connection.url in hibernate.cfg.xml - handling mulitple parameters

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Sometimes when I run my app, Hibernate notifies me about lost connection to MySql server. I found a solution on SO - add `autoReconnect=true` to connection url.

Problem is that I already have one parameter in my url. I tried adding above one with `&`, `?` and `;`, but none of them work.

My connection string:

```
<property name='connection.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull;autoReconnect=true</property>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using using `&amp;` instead of just amp to escape it for xml.

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true`